# Have gnuplot inherit the domain from pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I'm using `domain=min:max` within `pgfplots`, but unless I provide the same limits to `gnuplot` explicitly, they are ignored and `gnuplot` proceeds with plotting in the range `[-10,10]` (I assume that is the default range). Is there any way I can have `gnuplot` inherit the domain limits? If not, is there a way to pass them to `gnuplot` using`\pgfkeysvalueof{<whatever>}`?

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2,]

    \addplot3[raw gnuplot,surf,samples=20,]
      gnuplot[surf,] {%
        splot [-2:2] [-2:2] (1-x)^2 + 100*(y-x^2)^2
        % splot (1-x)^2 + 100*(y-x^2)^2 % This defaults in the range [-10,10].
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`raw gnuplot` disables the use of `samples` and `domain`.

You basically found the solution yourself: You can access the `domain` setting using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/domain}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2]

    \addplot3[raw gnuplot, surf,samples=20,]
      gnuplot{%
        splot [\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/domain}] [\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/domain}] (1-x)^2 + 100*(y-x^2)^2
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. I just didn't think it would be that easy. I thought it would break something. In a similar vein, do you know how I would set the domain when I'm using `gnuplot` like this:
`\addplot3[contour gnuplot={number{20},labels=true},samples=40,thick,] {x^2+y^2};`?

Comment: @sudosensei: In that case, you can use the normal `domain` key: `\addplot3[domain=-5:5, contour gnuplot={number={20},labels=true},samples=10,thick] {x^2+y^2};`. You only need that `\pgfkeysvalueof` approach if you're using `raw gnuplot`.

Comment: Excellent. Good to know that `raw gnuplot` ignores the values. Everything makes much more sense now. Thank you so much.