# TeX("$\lambda$") doesn't work in R

Tags: r

Im using the latex2exp package to make some plots in R with latex expressions in the labels. `TeX("$\lambda$")` on the xlabel doesn't print what it needs to. The documentation said to use  `TeX(r'($\lambda$)')` which doesnt work, and  `TeX("$\\lambda$")` doesnt work either. For example, `plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab = Tex(r'($\lambda$)'))` will not have the lambda character on the xlabel. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

With `knitr` and the `tikz` device there are no need of `latex2exp` and the `TeX()` function,  only escape the backslash.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<foo,echo=F,dev='tikz',fig.width=3, fig.height=3, fig.align='center'>>=
plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab = '$\\lambda$ with \\LaTeX')
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just installed those packages and tried it. It prints: $\lambda$

on the xlabel

Comment: @RobertFerydouni Have you tested just the above R Sweave file (save it with .Rnw extension)   "as is" or only the R chunk? I have included the expected output in the PDF.

Comment: Yes. It seems I have the same problem as my original comment. I do not have a latex compiler on my machine, could this be the problem? I try to import that library and it says "No Latex compiler could be found". So maybe it isnt noticing the $ symbols because of that

Comment: Of course, you need a latex compiler. Using R one way is installing [tinytex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tinytex/index.html)

Comment: I just installed tinytex, and I tried running the the R chunk only, as well as running the the file as is, and it still prints the characters '$\lambda$ with \LaTeX' on the xlabel. What else could this be attributed to

Comment: And have you installed the [tikzDevice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/)?

Comment: Yes I have. And knitr

Comment: Sure that you have run `install.packages('tinytex')` and then also `tinytex::install_tinytex()`?

Comment: Yes, I installed both. I also tried running that code on the console also, and I get a Error: unexpected input in "\" ,after the \documentclass{article} command. Similar erros show up with the "<<" and "@", so maybe the LaTeX commands aremt being recognized as LaTeX

Comment: You cannot do that, nor run only the R chunk. The .Rnw file **must** be converted to true .tex file and the compiled as any latex file. The way to do this is load the .Rnw file with Rstudio and click on the "compile PDF" icon or [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line) to use the command line.

Comment: I tried to click the Compile PDF button and got: LaTeX Error: File 'ae.sty' not found. Then below that it says: Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced. Also, this may or may not be important, but when I run the file or when I do what I jut did, this command automatically puts itself in the file: \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

Comment: (1)` \SweaveOpts`  should not appear. You are trying to compile the file with Sweave, not  with knitr. Check you RStudio configuration! (2) "*.sty not found": tinytex only  install a basic set of latex packages, but missing packages should be  downloaded  automatically when needed. If after some compilations still some file is not found, use `tlmgr` to install the missing latex packages.

Comment: Ah! I finally got your code to work. Thank you so much. How should I go about editing the above code, or writing a rnw file myself so I can generate my own plots? I tried copy and pasting some r code I had in between the << and the @ but that doesnt work. My code has a for loop generating multiple plots for different parameter values

Comment: I just tried clicking Compile PDF again but for my code with this method, but the pdf doesnt show any of the plots. I instead had a pathism command, which I checked all the plots were there, but I have the same problem of it printinig "$Latex expression$"

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Try first with some of the many working examples of  R plots using `.Rnw` files in this site, for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330428/tikz-vs-r-for-math-workbooks) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501031/11604)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html) of `latex2exp` mentions the following:

> Before R 4.0, it is necessary to escape the backslash within the
> string literal: therefore, one writes `'$\\gamma$'` rather than
> `'$\gamma$'` (the latter will cause an error).
>
> After R 4.0, it is recommended to use the new raw string literal
> syntax (see `?Quotes`). The syntax looks like `r"(...)"`, where `...` can
> contain any character sequence, including `\`:

You can find your R version when you start R, the version number is printed in the terminal window. Note that the R command is `TeX()` (so upper case T, lower case e, upper case X, which is the standard capitalization of TeX, and not Tex as written in the final snippet in the question - but I guess that is a typo.

The following works in R 3.6:

```r
library(latex2exp)
plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab = TeX("$\\lambda$"))
```

Result:

[image]

For R 4.0 and above you can use the new syntax. Note that you have to explicitly include the delimiter within the string. In the example above the delimiters are `'(` and `)'`. The following works when tested in R 4.0.3:

```r
library(latex2exp)
plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab = TeX(r'($\lambda$)'))
```

This does not work if you have the closing sequence `)'` somewhere inside of your string. In that case you can extend the delimiter with dashes, for example:

```r
plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab = TeX(r'---($\lambda\cdot(a+b)'$)---'))
# more readable:
plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab = TeX(
   r'---(
   $\lambda\cdot(a+b)'$
   )---'
))
```

Comment: I ave R version 4.0.4. I ran it with what you posted for R 4 and above, and I get a Error: malformed raw string literal

Comment: @RobertFerydouni strange. I'll try later if I can access a newer version of R to try out the syntax.

Comment: @RobertFerydouni I didn't put the correct delimiters in my 4.0+ example, now corrected.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. It prints: paste("", "", lambda, , , , "")  on the xlabel

Comment: @RobertFerydouni Maybe some of your packages need to be updated? I tried on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ with the code `library(latex2exp) print(R.version) plot(1:5, 1:5, xlab = TeX(r'($\lambda$)'))` which gives the expected plot (that website uses R 4.0.3). Or maybe there is an issue in how you store and run the code - do you type it directly in Rstudio, or do you run it from the command line/terminal, or through a file? Maybe there are some issues with interpreting/escaping special characters there, especially if it goes through the terminal.

Comment: I have been typing it directly into rstudio

Comment: I mentioned in the other answer that I have a pathism command directing the generated plots to a folder on my machine, and Im thinking it might be a problem with how the created pdfs are being stored

Comment: @Robert And does it work if you generate the plots in the RStudio plotting window, instead of saving it to a pdf?

Comment: No. Nothing even shows up in that window when I run the code that way. Im not sure if it can even do that, because I have a for loop generating multiple plots.

Comment: @Robert and what if you try just the code from your question, with the single plot of `1:5`? And does a single plot without LaTeX labels work?

Comment: The single plot does work both with and without latex expression, which leads me to think something is not working right with how my code is being processed.