# LaTeX expressions in xlabel of R plot

Tags: r

Im trying to print `$\lambda = $ lambda"` (where lambda outside of the dollar signs is a variable) on the xlabel of a plot I'm making in R using the `latex2exp` package. When I use:

```
xlab = paste(TeX(r'($\\lambda = $)'), lambda)
```

as is instructed for R version 4.0 and above (which I am using) it gives me:

> ", "", lambda, , , , phantom() == phantom(

on the xlabel in the pdf I created of the plot. When I use:

```
xlab = paste("$\\lambda = $", lambda)
```

It literally prints the characters:

> $\lambda = $ lambda

Im not sure what the significance of only one `\` showing up instead of two backslashes is. I tried asking about this problem in a different way in this thread: [TeX("$\lambda$") doesn't work in R](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591303/tex-lambda-doesnt-work-in-r) , but I couldnt figure it out. I dont want to use the sweave file method with the kntir and tikzDevice packages, I kind of want to figure out why `latex2exp` isnt working. Please help

Comment: This isn't really about TeX, but try `xlab = TeX(paste0("$\\lambda = ", lambda, "$"))`.

Comment: If the suggestion by @chsk does not work, then, continuing the comments from the other question: you said that a single plot with `latex2exp` works properly, so you concluded that there is a problem with your code for generating multiple plots. To find out what the problem is you therefore need to show the code that actually reproduces the problem. Show a full R script that, when executed from start to finish in R 4.x, results in the output you describe. Try to make it minimal, i.e., remove statements or details that are not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You might want to consider asking R-specific question on a different, better suited site, maybe stackoverflow.com. Here it is hardly on topic.